# Gunicorn not binding with nginx using socket

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

This is how my config looks like

```
#/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/testapp
ExecStart=/home/django/venvs/testenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock testapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And this is my nginx config:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testapp
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock;
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I run this command from my console:

```
/home/django/venvs/testenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock testapp.wsgi:application
```

then it shows like it is working in the console, but URL is still not accessible.

This is how the output looks like:

```
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1545] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1545] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock (1545)
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1545] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1548] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1548
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1550] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1550
[2016-07-11 16:29:41 -0400] [1551] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1551
```

But still, I am not able to access url of the server. I tried to open url with ports 80, 8000 and 9001, and neither one worked. (nginx is running on 80).

I am using python3.5 and gunicorn 19.6.0.

Does someone have any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem @bla0009? I am facing similar issues with flask? Posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/43754151/3834059

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the nginx configuration. Not sure about the socket but it looks fine with me.

You need to:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/testapp
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Then create a link from sites-available to sites-enable use:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/testapp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testapp
```

the run the command:

```
sudo service nginx configtest
```

It test that your nginx config files are good to go.  If it prompts `[OK]` then:

```
sudo servie nginx restart
```

Also the idea of nginx is to listen to domain names, not ports. Which is why i would recommend that you modify your host file 
Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` add a line like:
127.0.0.1       testapp 
and modify the nginx config file:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/testapp
server {
    server_name testapp;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/testapp/testapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Repeat steps to check nginx config file and restart nginx